# Send PHP POST hidden fields to angularjs and recieve in Controller

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, submit

I have a scenario in which PHP form is submitted with hidden fields and action has the URL of my AngularJS page.

Is there any way to get hidden fields from php in my angular sub-module?

I have seen some solutions for the opposite, i.e. submit the form from AngularJS-to-PHP, but no solution for PHP-to-AngularJS.

Comment: you do it with a single request usually: `$http.post("submit.php").then(function(res){console.log("get the response here:", res.data);})`

Comment: submit.php is the file where I am submitting the form? and Is this code to get posted data from php in angularjs controller?

Comment: yes, and if (after submission) it is processed immediately, then you should send it back from PHP to AngularJS so that it would receive it with `.then`. Otherwise I'm pretty sure you can't just send whatever you want from server to client (_otherwise you can just span everyone with requests that they didn't ask for_).